# How is source code compiled with MAUI to run on Android devices?

Tags: maui, maui-android

suppose I have written an app for an Android platform using MAUI, is the existence of  CoreCLR runtime on the phone a requirement for the execution of the app? Is there any AOT compilation scenario for the Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation process involves the following steps:

First, the C# code is compiled into Intermediate Language (IL) by the C# compiler.

Second, the IL code is then converted into native code for the target platform by using the Mono Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compiler or the .NET Native compiler.

Last, the native code is then packaged into an APK or AAB file by using the Android SDK tools.

> Is there any AOT compilation scenario for the Android app?

You can check this thread [[android] add AOT profile for .NET MAUI #2496](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/2496) to use the AOT compilation.